# Change the main scroll area on a webpage to stop at a certain point away from the bottom of viewport.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this situation:

```
.main-content {
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:3000px;
}



.fixed-menu {
  height:50px;
  background-color:pink;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:20px;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;

}

<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">

  </div>
  <div class="fixed-menu">
    Fixed menu at the bottom. The main content should stop above this bar, so the bar never overlaps the content when scrolling.
  </div>
</div>
```

When scrolling down, the pink bar should not overlap the blue content. It should behave as if the blue content was an iframe positioned 60px from the bottom of the page, but without using an iframe, and only css.

Anyone knows if this is possible? https://jsfiddle.net/0e98os22/2/r

Comment: _"Anyone knows if this is possible?"_ - this is a common problem, and if you include "footer" in your search keywords, you should be able to find plenty of resources. (Because most people ask this question with a fixed website footer in mind, but not necessarily containing a menu.)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put your content in an absolute div whose `top`, `left` and `right` are at `0`, but with `bottom:50px`. Another div, your menu, also absolute, with `bottom`, `left` and `right` at `0`, and with `height: 50px`. Then disable the page scrollbars using `overflow:hidden`.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  position: relative;  
  overflow: hidden;
}


.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-menu {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis justo sollicitudin, facilisis ante eget, ornare magna. Donec semper convallis orci, vitae consectetur arcu. Maecenas eu risus nec quam consequat tempus eu eget lectus. Vestibulum ultricies libero sit amet quam hendrerit facilisis. Donec auctor lorem est, eget malesuada felis tincidunt vitae. Suspendisse erat justo, auctor eu est non, hendrerit gravida nunc. Cras gravida urna id mattis pulvinar. Curabitur mattis, nunc a lacinia accumsan, tellus est porta quam, eget tempor tellus orci a elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet congue eros. Cras a molestie urna, a volutpat mauris. In ac viverra nulla, in sagittis turpis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis justo sollicitudin, facilisis ante eget, ornare magna. Donec semper convallis orci, vitae consectetur arcu. Maecenas eu risus nec quam consequat tempus eu eget lectus. Vestibulum ultricies libero sit amet quam hendrerit facilisis. Donec auctor lorem est, eget malesuada felis tincidunt vitae. Suspendisse erat justo, auctor eu est non, hendrerit gravida nunc. Cras gravida urna id mattis pulvinar. Curabitur mattis, nunc a lacinia accumsan, tellus est porta quam, eget tempor tellus orci a elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet congue eros. Cras a molestie urna, a volutpat mauris. In ac viverra nulla, in sagittis turpis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis justo sollicitudin, facilisis ante eget, ornare magna. Donec semper convallis orci, vitae consectetur arcu. Maecenas eu risus nec quam consequat tempus eu eget lectus. Vestibulum ultricies libero sit amet quam hendrerit facilisis. Donec auctor lorem est, eget malesuada felis tincidunt vitae. Suspendisse erat justo, auctor eu est non, hendrerit gravida nunc. Cras gravida urna id mattis pulvinar. Curabitur mattis, nunc a lacinia accumsan, tellus est porta quam, eget tempor tellus orci a elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet congue eros. Cras a molestie urna, a volutpat mauris. In ac viverra nulla, in sagittis turpis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis justo sollicitudin, facilisis ante eget, ornare magna. Donec semper convallis orci, vitae consectetur arcu. Maecenas eu risus nec quam consequat tempus eu eget lectus. Vestibulum ultricies libero sit amet quam hendrerit facilisis. Donec auctor lorem est, eget malesuada felis tincidunt vitae. Suspendisse erat justo, auctor eu est non, hendrerit gravida nunc. Cras gravida urna id mattis pulvinar. Curabitur mattis, nunc a lacinia accumsan, tellus est porta quam, eget tempor tellus orci a elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet congue eros. Cras a molestie urna, a volutpat mauris. In ac viverra nulla, in sagittis turpis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis justo sollicitudin, facilisis ante eget, ornare magna. Donec semper convallis orci, vitae consectetur arcu. Maecenas eu risus nec quam consequat tempus eu eget lectus. Vestibulum ultricies libero sit amet quam hendrerit facilisis. Donec auctor lorem est, eget malesuada felis tincidunt vitae. Suspendisse erat justo, auctor eu est non, hendrerit gravida nunc. Cras gravida urna id mattis pulvinar. Curabitur mattis, nunc a lacinia accumsan, tellus est porta quam, eget tempor tellus orci a elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet congue eros. Cras a molestie urna, a volutpat mauris. In ac viverra nulla, in sagittis turpis.
</div>
<div class="fixed-menu">
  Fixed menu at the bottom.
</div>
```

Comment: That's good, but it's using its own scrollbar. It should use the main scrollbar.

Comment: @user2475825 ahh. It's the other answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0e98os22/8/

Template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-menu">
    Fixed menu at the bottom. The main content should stop above this bar, so the bar never overlaps the content when scrolling.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.main-content img {
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed-menu {
  position:fixed;
  height:50px;
  background-color:pink;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work if you stack more blocks of content inside the main content, rather than having just an image there. If you have 10 paragraphs for example that extend the vertical space, the very bottom lines would be hidden behind the fixed bar if you scroll all the way down.

Comment: @user2475825 I don't think that's true. Added 3 images now and updated the fiddle. Even w/ the additional info it still works as expected.

Comment: If you add a small offset from the bottom on the fixed bar, you can see that the content still goes under the fixed bar: https://jsfiddle.net/0e98os22/7/ - it should be that the content stops above the pink bar.

Comment: @user2475825 Ah I see. Sorry I was thinkin who cares to be honest but I see your use case. Best bet for that will be an absolute position. Not ideal but I'll leave a fiddle example w/ that gimme 1 sec

Comment: @user2475825 Updated!

Comment: Thanks, but now the bottom of the last image is never visible. It should behave as if the images were in an iframe and the pink bar is always below it

Comment: @user2475825 There is a post at the bottom of each image including the last 1. I think you can see the bottom of that last image after you scroll down!